# Need to RUN multiple containers of the same image, Same config in same docker server using remote API

Tags: .net, docker, autoscaling, docker-container

I am new to Docker, Thank you for all the patience

I am trying to do some data processing using docker. My Application logic is this, rather than doing the entire data processing and machine learning prediction(python code) in single flow. I try trying to slice the Data based on certain filter conditions and run the processing in multiple docker containers.

1. How to RUN multiple containers on the same Host with same exposed
   ports.
2. How to use Docker.NET remote API to create a multiple
   containers of the same image on the same docker server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you will be able to expose the same port on the same host more than once, use another port thats the easiest way. you can run multiple instances by merely running it as `docker run <someImageId>`. You can start multiple instances using different (random) friendly names or you can use the name argument to docker run to give a more meaningful name

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Docker Swarm
2. Create Docker service with your app and replicas as needed (in your case 3)
3. Expose and Access it with the same URL